# How to run before all suites in ginkgo?

Tags: ginkgo

I'm integrating mock server to out tests. As part of it I need to clear all the request that was caught by mock server. Due to restrictions of the service we use, I can do it only once for all the endpoints. So I need to do it at the very begging before all suites, and only once.

It would be easy if we would run suits sequentially, but we run them in parallel.
How to implement before all suites in that case?